# For Input.Gettouch(0).phase==TouchPhase.Moved , How to store all touch positions in a array?

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

What I tried is as following

```
void Update () {
        if(Input.touchCount>0&&Input.GetTouch(0).phase==TouchPhase.Moved)
        {while(Input.GetTouch(0).phase==TouchPhase.Moved)
            {
                touches[i]= Input.GetTouch (0).position;
                i = i + 1;
            }
```

Error is in line touches[i]= Input.GetTouch (0).position;
Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the touch positions are already stored in `Input.touches`, which returns a collection of `Touch` objects. [An example is laid out in the Unity documentation here.](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input-touches.html)

For your case, you can still access the `phase` by querying the `touch.phase` in the `foreach (Touch touch in Input.touches)` loop. The reason you are getting an error is that, foreach loop does not operate with the index variable `i`. This would help you to store touch positions that has `TouchPhase.Moved` as the phase. Make sure that the `List<Vector2>` of positions are in the relevant scope.

```
List<Vector2> touchMovedPositions = new List<Vector2>();
if(Input.touchCount > 0)
{
    foreach((Touch touch in Input.touches) 
    {
        if(touch.phase == TouchPhase.Moved)
        {
            touchMovedPositions.Add(touch.position);
        }
    }
 }
```